# Android: PHP and mysql errors

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is more a two part question on the one subject.

I'm following this tutorial in an attempt to connect to mysql database through android (currently pc server):

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

The connection works fine, the app can download all the data using JSON, and as far as I can tell everything is in order.

There is a PHP script that queries the database using the variable 'year', which will cause an error in a browser:

> Undefined index 'year'

The android app still works fine however (collecting data using JSON); but by using the statement:

```
if (isset ..... 

{ // Query  }
```

The php errors disappear in the browser and unfortunately JSON stops working also in Android.

The way I'm seeing this problem is the program using a defined / set index correctly, then not working if it's being asked to check if it's set. Strange, but I'm probably missing something?

The other part is that I intended to use the same BasicNameValuePair with the $_REQUEST array for username & password ( currently causing some problems, but this may have to do with the other part). Is this a security risk, or is there nothing really different about using this method to pass the data along?

Thanks

Comment: Simple debugging check: `$data = json_decode(...); var_dump($data);`, just to see what Android is sending over. Given you get the undefined index, either it's not being sent, or it's in a different spot in the data structure than where you're referring to it.

Comment: about the risk i can tell you that the conection have to be scure HTTPS or coding data sent

Comment: and if you scroll down people already ask that in that tuto "ttps use polling | Sun, 04/10/2011 - 20:23.
Of course it is possible to use HTTPS and send password to access data, or do more complex data processing on either side, or write more general code

cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu"

Comment: @subspider - those arent real people.  those are spambots bro.  that's a line from the blog entry it harvested.

Comment: Thanks for the tips all. I don't think I can really help anyone else out for now, I'm just going to have to scroll through this new debug to find the problem.